# How to modify a list of lightning:recordEditForm in aura component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, process-builder, aura

```
submitDetails: function (component, event, helper) {   
    var selectCmp = event.getSource();
    console.log("selectCmp", selectCmp);
    var questions = component.find("questionEditForm");
    console.log("questions", questions);

    if (Array.isArray(questions) == true) {
      questions.forEach((form) => {
        console.log("form" + form);
        form.submit();
      });
    } else {
      questions.submit();
    }

    component.find("editForm").submit();
    component.set("v.isQuestionChange", false);
    
    console.log("check save");
  
  }
```

How can I modify the field value of each edit form before form.submit();
I have trouble when I modify things in the process builder then my aura page load before the process builder finish, the information don't up to date.

Comment: Do you have `recordEditForm` in an iteration?

Comment: hi @SachinHooda. Yeah, I am using it in an interation.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this :-

```
onSubmitHandler(event) {
event.preventDefault();
// Get data from submitted form
const fields = event.detail.fields;
// Here you can execute any logic before submit
// and set or modify existing fields
fields.Name = fields.Name + fields.Phone
// You need to submit the form after modifications
this.template
    .querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
```

}